# SQLite insertion with junction table

Tags: transaction, sqlite, many-to-many, source-code

I need to write a transaction for SQLite, that adds a blog post and links it to content tags, and it seems to be a bit too complicated for me. Here's an example schema:

```
CREATE TABLE blogpost(
       id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
       content TEXT
);

CREATE TABLE blogpost_tag(
       blogpost_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
       tag_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
       PRIMARY KEY (blogpost_id, tag_id), 
       FOREIGN KEY (blogpost_id) REFERENCES blogpost(id),
       FOREIGN KEY (tag_id) REFERENCES tag(id) ON DELETE CASCADE      
);

CREATE TABLE tag(
       id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
       name TEXT
);
```

I have the blog post content string and two tag strings, and now I need to write these into the database in an atomic transaction.

- The blog post content row need to be inserted into blogpost table.
- Let's assume that one of the tags already exists in tag table. Other one is new and needs to be inserted.
- Blogposts and tags have a many-to-many relationship, so I need to insert two rows to blogpost_tag table.

How do I write this transaction?

Comment: What programming language are you using?

Comment: I'm using php language

Comment: And what exactly do you have a problem with? Executing SQL commands? The syntax of SELECT or INSERT statements? `lastInsertRowid()`? Transactions?